# Elastic Kibana Visualize Use Range Aggregation on a String Field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm using elastic kibana Visualization and I have a field in the data that has a string value,
in my visualize I wanna use the range aggregation in order to make different group range of that field, however since the field is String value it does not show in Range aggregation field option.
what work around can be done to solve this issue? or maybe a way to use the data from another kibana chart in the Range aggregation Field option

Comment: I take that you don't have a `keyword` multi-field for that particular text field. Otherwise, you can do range aggregations over e.g. `field_name.keyword`

Comment: it does have a keyword however it does not appear in the range aggregation field selection , i have used the field.keyword for unique count before @glenacota